# How to make a share-this window drop when reaching end of post?

Tags: facebook, sharing

The following blog of okcupid had this interesting feature that shows a "share this" window only when you reach the end of the post:

http://blog.okcupid.com/index.php/what-if-there-were-not-so-many-white-people/

How is it possible to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Great question but nothing to do with WordPress.

Comment: Well, I wish to do it with WP :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They've attached a function to the scroll event of the page, it looks at the scroll position of the document relative to its height to detect when you've reached the bottom, in which case they animate the flyout div.

jQuery has some easy methods for this: `$(document).height();`, `$(document).scrollTop();`

edit: these may help [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837741/jquery-detecting-reaching-bottom-of-scroll-doesnt-work-only-detects-the-top) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036850/how-to-detect-page-scroll-to-a-certain-point-in-jquery)